# Update property on resource

Tags: api, rest

Is there a REST rule or best practice to update/create a specific property on a resource?  For example say I have a user resource.

/users (GET) gets all users, POST create a new one, and put /users/(id) updates the user with that  id.

Lets say I need to update a status for that person. I could just pass that in the PUT request, but problem is I want to delete the status as well. Usually with PUT I have only been updating the values passed, ie if you put with firstName=Bob I would update that persons firstName but I would not delete his lastName just because it was not passed in. As well as I would not delete status if it was not passed. So I need a way to delete status.

So I was thinking status was just another resource. But a very uncomplicated one.

/users/(id)/status POST to create a new status?  Problem I am trying to wrap my head around is that status is just a simple name, like 'away' or 'vacation'. Seems weird to do /users/(id)/status with a body of status=away. Ie status appears in URL and in body, seems wrong. Also with this approach POST and PUT would be identical. Maybe that is ok.

I feel like I have the simple cases of REST down but this one is stumping me.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would use PUT to create a new resource if you can describe it fully and as though it were a resource location. Use POST (with data) to update any portion of the resource that is hidden. Since status does not **identify** the resource, I think you should use POST.

Adding example:

```
POST /users HTTP/1.1
<user id="someID" >
  <status>newStatus</status>
</user>
```

Comment: Use post how?  Can you be more specific with an example. Are you saying /users/(id)/status POST. And pass status=away

Comment: Sure that is fine how do you delete a status if you are using /users to post a status?  Cause delete /users/(id) will delete that user.

Comment: Ah, that's different. I thought from your description that status was as singleton property of user. You referred to **update** a user status. If status is a multiple property implemented as a child of user (like status as of date), then it **is** a different resource and should have it's own interface using PUT to **add** a new status for a user.

Comment: PUT to add?  POST to add? I think you are starting to understand my question.

Comment: In general, if your status is something you can specify as a complete resource identifier, try to use PUT. So, if your status is something like "status of user on date", you know it all so put it. But name it as a resource like: /userstatus/userid/date/status. If the service needs to generate something (like a new ID or whatever) that will be returned to you to fully identify the resource, use POST. Delete it with /userstatus/userid/date